# Is there any way to compare two string similarity quantitatively

Tags: python, string

I have two strings say:

```
s_1 = "This is a bat"
s_2 = "This is a bag"
```

in a Qualitative manner they could be similar (1) or not (0), in the above case they are not similar because of "g",  while in quantitative manner i can see certain amount of dissimilarity is there how can i calculate this dissimilarity of one latter "g" from s_1 to s_2 using python.

I write down one simple code:

```
Per_deff = float(((Number_of_mutated_sites)/len(s_1))*100)
```

This code tells us "per_deff" between two string of identical length, what if they are not in identical length. How can i solve my problem.

Comment: You need to define the dissimilarity function. Here is an example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something that you want is similar to **Levenshtein Distance**. It gives you distance between two strings even if their lengths are not equal.

If two strings are exactly same then distance will be 0 and if they are similar then distance will be less.

Sample Code from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance):

```
// len_s and len_t are the number of characters in string s and t respectively
int LevenshteinDistance(string s, int len_s, string t, int len_t)
{ int cost;

  /* base case: empty strings */
  if (len_s == 0) return len_t;
  if (len_t == 0) return len_s;

  /* test if last characters of the strings match */
  if (s[len_s-1] == t[len_t-1])
      cost = 0;
  else
      cost = 1;

  /* return minimum of delete char from s, delete char from t, and delete char from both */
  return minimum(LevenshteinDistance(s, len_s - 1, t, len_t    ) + 1,
                 LevenshteinDistance(s, len_s    , t, len_t - 1) + 1,
                 LevenshteinDistance(s, len_s - 1, t, len_t - 1) + cost);
}
```

Comment: Dhanyawaad,  i will try to  translate it in "python"

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard python library [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#module-difflib)

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher


s_1 = "This is a bat"
s_2 = "This is a bag"
matcher = SequenceMatcher()
matcher.set_seqs(s_1, s_2)
print matcher.ratio()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called edit distance.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/editdistance

Edit distance is the number of edits needed to be made to one string to make it into the other string.

There is also as quick implementation here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24172422/4044442

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do fuzzy string matching. Multiple Python libraries exists for this, one of them is [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy).

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
s_1 = "This is a bat"
s_2 = "This is a bag"
fuzz.ratio(s_1, s_2)  # returns 92
fuzz.ratio(s_1, s_1)  # returns 100 (max score)
```