# Similarities between both strings

Tags: python, string

I am trying to compare the similarities between 2 strings. I did it successfully by   `import` `SequenceMatcher`

The result should only return 3 possibilities,

i) **Good** which means second string contains in the first string. Eg: *smack* and *mac*

ii) **Almost good** which means part of second string contained in first string. Eg: *smack* and *smart* . 
Both are 60% similar and should be classified as almost good.

iii)**Bad** which means none of the elements in second string contained in first string. Eg:*smack* and *van*

However, If I would like to perform the same task without importhing SequenceMatcher, how will I be able to perform it? I am stuck at writing an algorithm to slice the strings and compare it with another. Also, is there anyways to define the algorithm SequenceMatcher?

Here's a link to my code

```
Sa=input('enter something A: ')
Sb=input('enter something B: ')
Sc=Sa.lower()
Sd=Sb.lower()
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
if Sd in Sc or SequenceMatcher(a=Sc,b=Sd).ratio() ==1:
    print('Good') 

if Sd not in Sc and 0<SequenceMatcher(a=Sc,b=Sd).ratio() <1:
    print('Almost Good')

if SequenceMatcher(a=Sc,b=Sd).ratio() ==0:
    print('Bad')
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Sorry I am relatively new to stack exchange, Should I edit my post and paste the entire code on it?
Sorry for the confusion

Comment: i edited your code

Comment: Thank you for your kindness sachin dubey!

Comment: Perhaps look into 'edit distance' algorithms

Comment: @FujiApple Do you mind to explain or give an example of how we could use it to solve the problem? I'm still quite new in programming.
sachin dubey and I actually discussed a little more on the comment below. Kindly take a look. Thank you

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460177/edit-distance-in-python

Comment: May I know how do i set cost for each edit delete or substitution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `if-elif` instead of `If`

```
Sa=raw_input('enter something A: ')
Sb=raw_input('enter something B: ')
Sc=Sa.lower()
Sd=Sb.lower()

count = 0
for val in Sc:
    for char in Sd:
        if char == val:
            count = count + 1

if count == 0:
    print("Bad")
elif Sc in Sd or Sd in Sc:
    print('Good')
else:
    print('Almost Good')
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution and edit. works perfectly! Thanks once again!

Comment: may i know what should i do to limit the difference between 1 value of the string. The code you wrote returns almost good even for much and mars

Comment: which means, at most difference in n number of value is allowed to be different

Comment: I edited my post.Now check whether it is working correctly ? @MarcusKhoo

Comment: unfortunately, your code will still print *almost good* even with 1 alphabet that is same.

Comment: sorry ,But my code's output is exactly equal to your's.what should print if only one alphabet match ? @MarcusKhoo.

Comment: Don't be sorry :)  lets says there is 5 alphabets in both strings. Maximum number of difference allowed is only 1. So, 4/5 must be the same and according to sequence. For example *post* and *tops* they both are equally same alphabets. but it should be a bad string, because no alphabets are in the nth position of each other.

Comment: if there's n number of alphabets in the string,n-1 number of alphabet must correspond in another string for the system to print almost good string. Any value under n-1 is considered bad string , because there is more than 1 difference