# How to efficiently replace values in a large dataframe (100k+ rows) from another based on closest match?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So I am using levenshire distance to find closest match and replace many values in a large data frame using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64932433/7212929) as a base:

```
import operator

def levenshteinDistance(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) > len(s2):
        s1, s2 = s2, s1

    distances = range(len(s1) + 1)
    for i2, c2 in enumerate(s2):
        distances_ = [i2+1]
        for i1, c1 in enumerate(s1):
            if c1 == c2:
                distances_.append(distances[i1])
            else:
                distances_.append(1 + min((distances[i1], distances[i1 + 1], distances_[-1])))
        distances = distances_
    return distances[-1]

def closest_match(string, matchings):
    scores = {}
    for m in matchings:
        scores[m] = 1 - levenshteinDistance(string,m)
    
    return max(scores.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

So while replacing many values in a moderately large dataframe (100k+ rows) from another of the similar size as follows takes forever to run: (Running from last half hour ha!)

```
results2.products = [closest_match(string, results2.products) 
                    if string not in results2.products else string 
                    for string in results.products]
```

So is there a way to do this more efficiently? I added if-else condition  for the same purpose so that if there is a direct match there wont be any calculations involved which also would have produced same result.

### Sample Data

`results`:

```
   products
0, pizza
1, ketchup
2, salami
3, anchovy
4, pepperoni
5, marinara
6, olive
7, sausage
8, cheese
9, bbq sauce
10, stuffed crust
```

`results2`:

```
   products
0, salaaaami
1, kechap
2, lives
3, ppprn
4, pizzas
5, marinara
6, sauce de bbq
7, marinara sauce
8, chease
9, sausages
10, crust should be stuffed
```

I want values in `results2` to be replaced by the closest match in `results`

Comment: can you paste some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan Added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### So I took a couple of measures to improve speed and have almost 4800x speedup.

Posting here to benefit anyone dealing with slow performance of any CPU-intensive task on pandas:

1. Instead of replacing all at once as in the question, I made a replacement dictionary to make replacements with unique values in each dataframe which made it to go from taking forever (I stopped after 2 hours) to a 2 minutes as there are many many repeated values. Thats a 60x speedup:

   ```
   replacements = {string: closest_match(string, results2.products.unique())
                 if string not in results2.products.unique() else string 
                   for string in results.products.unique()}
   results.replace({'products':replacements}, inplace = True)
   ```
2. I used a c-based implementation of calculating levenshtein distance making use of : [editdistance](https://pypi.org/project/editdistance/0.3.1/) library. On research I found that many such tasks have C-based implementations like matrix-multiplication and search algorithms etc. are readily available. Besides you can always write a module in C and make use of it in python.
   `editdistance.eval('banana', 'bahama')` took only `1.71 µs ± 289 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)` in comparison with my defined function `levenshteinDistance('banana', 'bahama')` which took `34.4 µs ± 4.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)` That’s a 20x speedup. Resultant `closest_match() function`:

   ```
   import operator
   import editdistance
   def closest_match(string, matchings):
       scores = {}
       for m in matchings:
           scores[m] = 1 - editdistance.eval(string,m)

       return max(scores.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
   ```
3. Then I made use of all of my cores at once by parallelism. For that I have gone through various alternatives e.g. multiprocessing and threading but none of them gave a comparison as fast as of [modin.pandas](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Its minimal changes (just one line import `modin.pands as pd` in place of `import pandas as pd`) and work elegantly. It made previous runs around 4x faster.

Thus totaling a 4800x speedup which is massive and whole thing is running in a blink.

### UPDATE

I got a massive amounts of products so was looking for further optimizations. Turned out vectorization was the answer. Now my updated closest match function looks like:

```
results.index = results.products
def closest_match_results_product(string):
    return results.products.apply(lambda x: editdistance.eval(string,x)).idxmin()
```

And applying this function looks like:

```
results2.products = results2.products.apply(closest_match_results_product)
```

Bam! More optimized than ever! Still if there is further room for improvement would love to see any suggestions!

Comment: Great answer definitely book marking this

Answer (score 1):

Use compiled Python.

Use Cython / CPython

Use PyPy aka Stackless Python

Use Numba for both your function as follows:

```
from numba import jit
@jit
def levenshteinDistance(s1, s2):
...
```

Comment: psyco is dead since 2012. Even then its only for 32-bit python and obviously in 2020 I'm running 64-bit version: https://superuser.com/questions/195047/how-to-install-psyco-getting-no-python-installation-found-in-registry

Comment: @jit supports (parallel = True, no_python = True) implementations for faster executions but both flags are unavailable for the datatypes I am using. without these flags I left it to run but warnings showed it falls back to string/ other datatypes I am using and had no obvious speed advantage. Even then I let it run but it didnt get anywhere after 2 hours. it was still running and I stopped it.