# Asyncio coroutine returns <_GatheringFuture pending> instead of actual values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

So I am trying to replace a bunch of values in one dataframe from another namely `results` and `results2` . I want values in `results2` to be replaced by the closest match in `results` which look like:

`results`:

```
   products
0, pizza
1, ketchup
2, salami
3, anchovy
4, pepperoni
5, marinara
6, olive
7, sausage
8, cheese
9, bbq sauce
10, stuffed crust
```

`results2`:

```
   products
0, salaaaami
1, kechap
2, lives
3, ppprn
4, pizzas
5, marinara
6, sauce de bbq
7, marinara sauce
8, chease
9, sausages
10, crust should be stuffed
```

[Both dataframes are fairly large so calculating levenshteinDistance was taking forever.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64935187/how-to-efficiently-replace-values-in-a-large-dataframe-100k-rows-from-another) So I tried making use of asyncio as follows:

```
async def levenshteinDistance(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) > len(s2):
        s1, s2 = s2, s1

    distances = range(len(s1) + 1)
    for i2, c2 in enumerate(s2):
        distances_ = [i2+1]
        for i1, c1 in enumerate(s1):
            if c1 == c2:
                distances_.append(distances[i1])
            else:
                distances_.append(1 + min((distances[i1], distances[i1 + 1], distances_[-1])))
        distances = distances_
    return distances[-1]

async def closest_match(string, matchings):
    scores = {}
    for m in matchings:
        scores[m] = 1 - levenshteinDistance(string,m)
    
    return await max(scores.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]

results2.products = asyncio.gather(*[closest_match(string, results.products.values) 
                    if string not in results.products else string 
                    for string in results2.products])
results2
```

Placing or removing `await` (as suggested by various answers on SO) here has no advantage as it will return `<_GatheringFuture pending>` instead of actual values thus not waiting at all. I tried making use of a separate caller function (some answers I saw) to wait for them before returning results as:

```
async def caller(results, results2):
    return await asyncio.gather(*[closest_match(string, results.products.values) 
                    if string not in results.products else string 
                    for string in results2.products]) 

#and changing last lines as:
results2.products = caller(results, results2)
results2
```

But now it only returns `<coroutine object caller at 0x000001FE173742B0>` so it is actually not waiting but returning coroutine itself. Any bits I am missing out on?

P.S. I am running python 3.6 so cannot make use of `asyncio.create_task()` or `asyncio.run()`

Comment: Asyncio is an IO-centric cooperative multitasking system and will not speed up CPU-bound tasks. The giveaway that asyncio is useless is that your bottom-most `async def`s don't await anything - such "coroutines" will be executed sequentially. Having said that, at top-level you should be using something like `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(caller(...))`. Also, `await max(..., ...)` can never work because `max` is not async.

Comment: So @user4815162342 by what I got from you is even if I made asyncio based version work, there won't be any speed advantage at all! So any way I can better my situation in linked question?

Comment: You could try to speed it up using multiprocessing, [like this](https://pastebin.com/098t5C84). But an even better option would be to use a native library for levenshtein distance, perhaps [this one](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/). (Disclaimer: I've never used that library, I just found it now using google.)