# Fastet way to create a new dataframe from two diffrenet dataframes with diffrenet sizes while perserving duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with diffrenet sizes (df1 is larger than df2):

```
df1:
coulmn 1(contains duplicates) column 2 (unique)
A                                B
A                                C
G                                H

df2
coulmn 3(contains duplicates) column 4
A                               1
A                               1
G                               0
```

I want to create a new dataframe where column 3 is equal to coulmn 1 (including duplicate matches) and I want to grab values from column 2 and coulmn 4.
I want my resulting df to look like this:

```
column 2   column 4
B            1
C            1
H            0
```

what is the fastest way to implement this on millions of rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply merge them on these columns and have result deduplicated:

```
df1.merge(df2, right_on='column 3', left_on='column 1')[['column 2', 'column 4']].drop_duplicates()
```

Result will look like:

|  | column 2 | column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | B | 1 |
| 2 | C | 1 |
| 4 | H | 0 |

Comment: This is not efficient when dealing with millions of rows. The method is sound though...

Comment: Merging IS the most efficient pandas way for these types of use cases. If your dataset has  millions of rows rthen you might need to look for alternatives like `dask` or have some optimizations as in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64976482/7212929